# C# Errors - Impossible to load Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-assembly

I have problem's with a C# project.

The error when i start my application :

> URI de démarrage :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xbap Identité de
>   l'application :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xbap#xxxxxxxxxx.xbap,
>   Version=1.0.0.212, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000,
>   processorArchitecture=msil/xxxxxxxxxx.exe, Version=1.0.0.212,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000,
>   processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
>
> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Impossible de charger le
>   fichier ou l'assembly 'MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   ou une de ses dépendances. La définition trouvée du manifeste de
>   l'assembly ne correspond pas à la référence de l'assembly. (Exception
>   de HRESULT : 0x80131040)
>   ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, PublicKeyToken=null' ou une de
>   ses dépendances. La définition trouvée du manifeste de l'assembly ne
>   correspond pas à la référence de l'assembly. (Exception de HRESULT :
>   0x80131040)    à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    à
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    à
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    à
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)    à
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveAssembly(BamlAssembly
>   bamlAssembly)    à
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlTypeToType(BamlType
>   bamlType)    à
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(BamlType
>   bamlType, Int16 typeId)    à
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType(Int16
>   typeId)    à
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_ElementStart()    à
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord()    à
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_BamlRecords()    à
>   System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Read()    à
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader
>   xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode,
>   Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo,
>   IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer
>   xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector
>   styleConnector)    à
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)    --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception
>   interne ---    à System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader
>   xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)    à
>   System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader,
>   Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel
>   accessLevel, Uri baseUri)    à
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext
>   parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)    à
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri
>   resourceLocator)    à xxxxxxxxxx.App.InitializeComponent()    à
>   xxxxxxxxxx.App.Main()    à
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    à System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)    à System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean
>   checkAptModel)    à
>   System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()    à
>   System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)    à
>   System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext)    à
>   System.Windows.Interop.PresentationApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   actCtx)    à System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext)    à System.AppDomain.Setup(Object arg)    à
>   System.AppDomain.nCreateInstance(String friendlyName, AppDomainSetup
>   setup, Evidence providedSecurityInfo, Evidence creatorsSecurityInfo,
>   IntPtr parentSecurityDescriptor)    à
>   System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstanceHelper(AppDomainSetup
>   adSetup)    à
>   System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)    à
>   System.Windows.Interop.PresentationApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   actCtx)    à System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext
>   activationContext)    à
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.ExecuteNewDomain()
>   à System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.Execute()    à
>   MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.ExecuteDownloadedApplication()
>   à System.Windows.Interop.DocObjHost.RunApplication(ApplicationRunner
>   runner)    à
>   MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.RunApplicationAsyncCallback(Object
>   unused)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   à System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)    à
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    à
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    à
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    à
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    à
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    à
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   à
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    à
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>   à System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)    à
>   System.Windows.Application.StartDispatcherInBrowser(Object unused)
>   à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   à System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)    à
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    à
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    à
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    à
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    à
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    à
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    à
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   à
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>
> ---
>
> PresentationHost.exe v4.0.41210.0 built by: Main -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PresentationHost.exe ntdll.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll kernel32.dll
>   v6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll KERNELBASE.dll v6.1.7601.18015
>   (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432) - C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
>   ADVAPI32.dll v6.1.7601.23864 (win7sp1_ldr.170707-0600) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll msvcrt.dll v7.0.7601.17744
>   (win7sp1_gdr.111215-1535) - C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll sechost.dll
>   v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll RPCRT4.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll SspiCli.dll
>   v6.1.7601.23864 (win7sp1_ldr.170707-0600) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll CRYPTBASE.dll v6.1.7601.23864
>   (win7sp1_ldr.170707-0600) - C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
>   USER32.dll v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll GDI32.dll v6.1.7601.23807
>   (win7sp1_ldr.170512-0600) - C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll LPK.dll
>   v6.1.7601.23807 (win7sp1_ldr.170512-0600) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll USP10.dll v1.0626.7601.23807
>   (win7sp1_ldr.170512-0600) - C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll ole32.dll
>   v6.1.7601.23775 (win7sp1_ldr.170417-0600) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll OLEAUT32.dll v6.1.7601.23775 -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll mscoree.dll v4.0.40305.0
>   (Main.040305-0000) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll SHLWAPI.dll
>   v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll WININET.dll v11.00.9600.18763
>   (winblue_ltsb_escrow.170713-1619) - C:\Windows\syswow64\WININET.dll
>   api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492
>   (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll
>   api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492
>   (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll
>   api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492
>   (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll
>   version.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.DLL
>   api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492
>   (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll
>   normaliz.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\normaliz.DLL iertutil.dll v11.00.9600.18763
>   (winblue_ltsb_escrow.170713-1619) - C:\Windows\syswow64\iertutil.dll
>   api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492
>   (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll
>   USERENV.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\USERENV.dll profapi.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\profapi.dll urlmon.dll
>   v11.00.9600.18763 (winblue_ltsb_escrow.170713-1619) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\urlmon.dll api-ms-win-downlevel-ole32-l1-1-0.dll
>   v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\api-ms-win-downlevel-ole32-l1-1-0.dll SHELL32.dll
>   v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll IMM32.DLL v6.1.7601.17514
>   (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL MSCTF.dll
>   v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
>   PresentationHost_v0400.dll v4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationHost_v0400.dll
>   VCRUNTIME140_CLR0400.dll v14.10.25028.0 built by: VCTOOLSD15RTM -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\VCRUNTIME140_CLR0400.dll ucrtbase_clr0400.dll
>   v14.10.25028.0 built by: VCTOOLSD15RTM -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase_clr0400.dll PSAPI.DLL v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
>   api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.DLL v10.0.10586.788
>   (th2_release_sec.170113-1732) -
>   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.DLL CLBCatQ.DLL
>   v2001.12.8530.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL CRYPTSP.dll v6.1.7601.23471
>   (win7sp1_ldr.160614-0600) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CRYPTSP.dll rsaenh.dll
>   v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll RpcRtRemote.dll v6.1.7601.17514
>   (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll
>   ieproxy.dll v11.00.9600.18763 (winblue_ltsb_escrow.170713-1619) -
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll
>   api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l2-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492
>   (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l2-1-0.dll
>   Secur32.dll v6.1.7601.23864 (win7sp1_ldr.170707-0600) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Secur32.dll
>   api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l2-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492
>   (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l2-1-0.dll
>   WS2_32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll NSI.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll mswsock.dll
>   v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll wship6.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll IPHLPAPI.DLL
>   v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL WINNSI.DLL v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WINNSI.DLL dfshim.dll
>   v4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dfshim.dll
>   mscoreei.dll v4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll clr.dll
>   v4.8.3928.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll msxml6.dll
>   v6.30.7601.18980 - C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll bcrypt.dll
>   v6.1.7601.23864 (win7sp1_ldr.170707-0600) -
>   C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll SXS.DLL v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SXS.DLL
>   PresentationHostProxy.dll v4.0.40305.0 built by: Main -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PresentationHostProxy.dll mscorlib.ni.dll
>   v4.8.3928.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\36eaccfde177c2e7b93b8dbdde4e012a\mscorlib.ni.dll nlssorting.dll v4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
>   System.ni.dll v4.8.3928.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\2c3c912ea8f058f9d04c4650128feb3f\System.ni.dll
>   System.Core.ni.dll v4.8.4110.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\cb2be6124621944bbf0cc583680af6d2\System.Core.ni.dll
>   WindowsBase.ni.dll v4.8.4110.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\1d887c8c7bc720de65126c65a6a1ee8e\WindowsBase.ni.dll
>   PresentationCore.ni.dll v4.8.4110.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore\bc4064b0af8acc0dc3c409dc25f27563\PresentationCore.ni.dll
>   PresentationFramework.ni.dll v4.8.4110.0 -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Presentatio5ae0f00f#\2671c8ec359d27c438a3ab287c467ec6\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
>   dwrite.dll v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\system32\dwrite.dll wpfgfx_v0400.dll v4.8.4110.0 built by:
>   NET48REL1LAST_B -
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
>   MSVCP140_CLR0400.dll v14.10.25028.0 built by: VCTOOLSD15RTM -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCP140_CLR0400.dll PresentationNative_v0400.dll
>   v4.8.4110.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B -
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationNative_v0400.dll
>   System.Xaml.ni.dll v4.8.4110.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xaml\cf453bee14beca2aa25d4f2bc92aacb6\System.Xaml.ni.dll
>   System.Configuration.ni.dll v4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\5154079f7b4c6327f4c479840c6212a4\System.Configuration.ni.dll
>   System.Xml.ni.dll v4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\15af16d373cf0528cb74fc73d365fdbf\System.Xml.ni.dll
>   System.Deployment.ni.dll v4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Deployment\0f1bc8003ad4f90d17c5b61431ff678a\System.Deployment.ni.dll
>   mshtml.dll v11.00.9600.18763 (winblue_ltsb_escrow.170713-1619) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshtml.dll UxTheme.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\UxTheme.dll comctl32.dll
>   v6.10 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_41e855142bd5705d\comctl32.dll
>   rasapi32.dll v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\system32\rasapi32.dll rasman.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\rasman.dll rtutils.dll
>   v6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rtutils.dll wshtcpip.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll winhttp.dll
>   v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\system32\winhttp.dll webio.dll v6.1.7601.17514
>   (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll credssp.dll
>   v6.1.7601.23864 (win7sp1_ldr.170707-0600) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\credssp.dll dhcpcsvc6.DLL v6.1.7601.17970
>   (win7sp1_gdr.121009-0412) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
>   dhcpcsvc.DLL v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.DLL msimtf.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\msimtf.dll msls31.dll
>   v3.10.349.0 - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msls31.dll d2d1.dll v6.2.9200.16492
>   (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d2d1.dll dxgi.dll
>   v6.2.9200.16492 (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll dwmapi.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll CFGMGR32.dll
>   v6.1.7601.17621 (win7sp1_gdr.110523-2108) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll WINTRUST.dll v6.1.7601.23769
>   (win7sp1_ldr.170412-0600) - C:\Windows\syswow64\WINTRUST.dll
>   CRYPT32.dll v6.1.7601.23769 (win7sp1_ldr.170412-0600) -
>   C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll MSASN1.dll v6.1.7601.17514
>   (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850) - C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll DNSAPI.dll
>   v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DNSAPI.dll d3d11.dll v6.2.9200.16570
>   (win8_gdr.130327-1526) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll rasadhlp.dll
>   v6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll fwpuclnt.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll IEFRAME.dll
>   v11.00.9600.18763 (winblue_ltsb_escrow.170713-1619) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IEFRAME.dll
>   api-ms-win-downlevel-shell32-l1-1-0.dll v6.2.9200.16492
>   (win8_gdr_oobssr.130113-0015) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-downlevel-shell32-l1-1-0.dll
>   uiautomationcore.dll v7.0.0.0 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uiautomationcore.dll OLEACC.dll v7.0.0.0
>   (win7sp1_gdr.110826-1504) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OLEACC.dll
>   jscript9.dll v11.00.9600.18763 (winblue_ltsb_escrow.170713-1619) -
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\jscript9.dll bcryptprimitives.dll v6.1.7601.23451
>   (win7sp1_ldr.160511-0600) - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll
>   windowscodecs.dll v6.2.9200.21830 (win8_ldr.160407-0600) -
>   C:\Windows\system32\windowscodecs.dll mlang.dll v6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) - C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
>   api-ms-win-core-xstate-l2-1-0.dll v10.0.10586.788
>   (th2_release_sec.170113-1732) -
>   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-xstate-l2-1-0.dll clrjit.dll
>   v4.8.3928.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
>   System.Drawing.ni.dll v4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\f7568d7f1b9d356f64779b4c0927cfb3\System.Drawing.ni.dll
>   System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll v4.8.3928.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\27c4749406e44b1ba8a9ddda88e72add\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
>   System.Security.ni.dll v4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Security\93d03eb9812405fa70e89d4efd5f7e14\System.Security.ni.dll
>   gdiplus.dll v6.1.7601.23807 (win7sp1_ldr.170512-0600) -
>   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.23807_none_5c02a265a011fb02\gdiplus.dll
>   diasymreader.dll v14.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1 -
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll

Someone could help me ?

Thank's

Comment: Assembly `MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf` can not be loaded. Have you tried restoring nuget packages for your solution?

Comment: Do you think you may have a cross-threading issue.

Comment: I tried to delete and reload MaterialDesignThemes.
The same.

I don't understand your second answer.

Thanks again.